# Сохранение листов как отдельные книги с датой

Tags: excel, vba

Макрос копирует часть информации с одного листа на другой (таких листов источников и получателей несколько). Возможно ли сохранить листы получатели, сейчас это "Чел из формы" и "Нвс из формы" как отдельные книги с разными путями сохранения и с текущей датой в названии? дату добавить как & Format(Date, "dd.mm.yyyy")?

```html
Sub test()
    Dim currColumn As Object
    Dim mstr As String

    With Worksheets("Чел из формы")
        For I = 1 To 9
            mstr = Array("Товарная группа", "Номенклатура", "Название номенклатуры", "КП", "*КЛ", "Статус номенклатуры", "Розничная цена", "Ост. ЦС", "Объем")(I - 1)
            Set currCell = .Cells.Find(What:=mstr, SearchFormat:=False, LookAt:=xlWhole)
            .Columns(currCell.Column).Copy Worksheets("Чел").Columns(I)
        Next I
    End With
    
    With Worksheets("Нвс из формы")
        For I = 1 To 9
            mstr = Array("Товарная группа", "Номенклатура", "Название номенклатуры", "КП", "КЛ", "Статус номенклатуры", "Розничная цена", "РЦ Ост.", "Объем")(I - 1)
            Set currCell = .Cells.Find(What:=mstr, SearchFormat:=False, LookAt:=xlWhole)
            .Columns(currCell.Column).Copy Worksheets("Нвс").Columns(I)
        Next I
    End With

    Worksheets("Чел").Columns(1).ColumnWidth = 40
    Worksheets("Чел").Columns(2).ColumnWidth = 5
    Worksheets("Чел").Columns(3).ColumnWidth = 40
    Worksheets("Нвс").Columns(1).ColumnWidth = 40
    Worksheets("Нвс").Columns(2).ColumnWidth = 5
    Worksheets("Нвс").Columns(3).ColumnWidth = 40
    Set currColumn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Да, возможно. Включите запись макроса. Выполните такое сохранение вручную. Остановите запись. Отрихтуйте полученный код под свои нужды.

Comment: *как мне записью сохранить несколько листов в несколько книг.* А по одному. *Допустим я удалю все не нужные листы, сохраню нужный* На зачем удалять-то? Топни правым батоном по ярлыку с именем листа, выбери "Переместить или скопировать...", да укажи, что копировать в новую книгу - и вот её-то и сохраняй.

Comment: Зачем показывать код, который не имеет никакого отношения к вопросу? Получается, у Вас только вопрос. без каких-либо попыток сделать что-либо самостоятельно.

Comment: Не знал, про то что лист можно копировать в новую книгу, пробую сделать. спасибо. Код, я думал его дополнить будет проще, чем делать отдельный макрос.

Comment: Не связанные действия правильнее оформлять отдельными процедурами, с передачей нужных параметров между ними. В Вашем случае достаточно в конце процедуры (после заполнения листов) вызвать новую, которая обработает создание новых книг.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub CreateAndSave(SheetName As String)
Dim wbk As Workbook
Set wbk = Workbooks.Add
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetName).Copy Before:=wbk.Sheets(1)
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
For i = 2 To wbk.Sheets.Count
    wbk.Sheets(2).Delete
Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
wbk.SaveAs Filename:=SheetName & " - " & Format(Date, "dd.mm.yyyy") & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
wbk.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: спасибо, но я вроде первым способом справился, надо потестировать)

Comment: @Akina, правильнее удалять листы сверху вниз (*Step -1*)

Comment: @vikttur Это ещё почему? Я лично вообще не вижу разницы, кроме длины кода (у меня, кстати, код короче). А если хочется совсем правильно, то нужно вспомнить, что это - коллекция, и её нужно `For Each .. If Sheet.Name <> .. Then Delete`

Comment: @Akina, разница в том, что на каждом витке цикла дополнительно происходит пересчет верхней границы цикла. Для обратного отсчета это не нужно. Можно проверить: `k = Sheets.Count`:  
   `For i = 2 To k` / `For i = k To 2 Step -1` Второе - логически правильнее удалять листы с последнего до нужного, а не каждый раз лист №2.=== По поводу *For Each* - не лучше. Нужна дополнительная проверка имени. А если нужно оставить несколько копированных листов, то еще усложнение.

Comment: @vikttur *на каждом витке цикла дополнительно происходит пересчет верхней границы цикла* Не говорите ерунды. Границы цикла считаются при его формировании и в дальнейшем не пересчитываются. Поставьте внутри цикла брейк и вручную удалите последний лист - out of range гарантирован.

Comment: @Akina, извините. Таки да, ерунду написал. Засомневался, а все из-за того, что неправильно проверку сделал. https://www.planetaexcel.ru/forum/index.php?PAGE_NAME=read&FID=1&TID=118786&TITLE_SEO=118786-opredelenie-granits-tsikla-fornext